# Highcharts how to make the y axis series value return only 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image]

I want to make the format of my y axis series to only return 2 decimal places.

I have this code:

```
$('#main-graph').highcharts({
        chart:{
            zoomType:'xy',
            type: 'spline'
        },
        title: {
            text: '',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: stat_date,
            crosshair:true,
        },
        yAxis: [
        { //0
            title: {
                text: 'Impressions'
            },
        },
        {//1
            title:{
                text: "Clicks"
            }
        },
        { //2
            title:{
                text: "CTR"
            }
        },
        { //3
            title:{
                text: "CPM"
            }
        },
        { //4
            title:{
                text: "CPC"
            }
        },
        { //5 - secondary axis which is the SPEND axis
            title: {
                text: "Spend",
                style:{
                     // color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                     color: "#8B8B8B"
                }
            },
            opposite:true
        }],
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            valueDecimals: 2
            // pointFormat: "{point.y:,.2f}"
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            align: 'top',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            borderWidth: 0,
            floating:true,
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Spend',
            data: spend,
            yAxis: 5,
            type:'column'
        }, {
            name: 'Impressions',
            data: imp,
            yAxis: 0,
        }, {
            name: 'Clicks',
            data: clicks,
            yAxis: 1
        },
        {
            name: 'CTR',
            data: ctr,
            yAxis: 2
        }, {
            name: 'CPM',
            data: cpm,
            yAxis: 3
        }, {
            name: 'CPC',
            data: cpc,
            yAxis: 4
        }
        ]
    });
}
```

I tried adding this line of code:

```
dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    formatter: function () {
        return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,2);
    }
}
```

but it isn't working.

Any ideas? your help will be grealty apprecaited!

Thanks!

Comment: What if you change all `formatter` function to `format: '{point.y:,.2f}`?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado where would I put that? should that be inside or outside my series:[{}] ?

Comment: Just where `formatter`is, replacing it. (this is a wild guess!)

Comment: @GerardoFurtado still not working bud :)

Comment: You may use .toFixed(2) in your case. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

Comment: I guess that your labels are printed on yAxis, so you need to use formatter / format in yAxis.labels.format / yAxis.labels.formatter instead of datalabels.